# Как легко и быстро создать дамп базы postgresql данных со схемами и данными потом добавить дамп на другой сервер?

Tags: postgresql, dump

Как легко и быстро создать дамп базы postgresql данных со схемами и данными потом добавить дамп на другой сервер?

Comment: набрать в гугле "postgresql dump". https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html

Comment: @Mike пишет error . Я так делал

Comment: @Mike ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "pg_dump") Позиция: 1 . Я так пробовал уже, естественно- погуглил

Comment: pg_dump это утилита командной строки, ее не надо выполнять из sql. ее надо выполнять из командной строки вашей ОС

Comment: @Mike сделал так, но создался пустой файл...странно. Я написал pg_dump mydbname > c:\Server\outfile.sql

Comment: вы ее без перенаправления запустите и что бы консоль не закрылась после нее, там наверняка в командной строке надо всякие логины/пароли еще передавать

Comment: @Mike теперь пишет, что он не знает pg_dump . Странно,я думал- Postgresql пропишет в переменные среды. А как его прописать туда?

Comment: я пропишу тупо путь до файла тогда

Comment: не знаю, найдите его и пишите полный путь

Comment: "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_dump.exe" --username=postgres   mafiadb > c:\Server\outfile.sql   Всё заработало. Спасибо